# Favicon not showing in masterpage

Tags: asp.net, master-pages, favicon

I am trying tp put favicon in masterpage but its not showing on browser, VS shows no error

Master page code

```
     <head runat="server">
            <title>My Test Application</title>
            <link href="~/Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
            <link id="Link1" runat="server" rel="shortcut icon" href="~/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
            <link id="Link2" runat="server" rel="icon" href="~/favicon.ico" type="image/ico" />
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadContent" runat="server">
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </head>
```

Comment: first of all which browser you are using ?
**<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" />**
its not working?

which folder you are saving image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace this:

```
<link id="Link1" runat="server" rel="shortcut icon" href="~/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
<link id="Link2" runat="server" rel="icon" href="~/favicon.ico" type="image/ico" />
```

With

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="~/favicon.ico" />
```

You can download standard icon [here](http://www.iconarchive.com/download/i41029/emey87/social-button/tree.ico).

http://www.iconarchive.com

Comment: still same problem  . .

Answer (score 2):

Just copy your favicon.ico to root older while deploying. And clear all your browser cookies before testing. It will surely show up.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
```

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: was using Google Chrome . . .